# I need change the pagination url structure, p=2 to page/2

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, pagination

I need to change the structure of the pagination's url to be more friendly,

I have tried do it using .htaccess, and I have tested the RewriteRule on online tools. but in my website it always give me a 404 error

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/page/([1-9]+)$ /$1?p=$2 [QSA,L]
```

I can't  found solutions for this issue

Answer (score 0):

You are restructuring the request URL only, There is no valid page at this location.  You need to create a valid route for your pages to accept this. - Seo suite can allow you to do this.  without any additional rewrites.